Do we use a preposition after "use". For example:
Grammarly is not allowed to be used neither quizzes nor exams. Is this sentence correct?

Yes, when we say how or in what circumstances we use something, a preposition is needed. Toothpaste is used for cleaning our teeth. Grammarly is not allowed to be used in either quizzes or exams.

@KateBunting Are you sure about your version? I took it that the OP wants a sentence forbidding use of Grammarly in quizzes and forbidding Grammarly in exams; your version might mean that it is forbidden in quizzes or it is forbidden in exams but possibly not both. (Unlikely in real life, but from a grammatical point of view sustainable?)

@erstwhileeditor - I don't agree. Not allowed in either A or B means forbidden in both.

@KateBunting I stand corrected; thanks.

No it is not correct.  A better way to phrase it would be
Grammarly is not allowed to be used in either quizzes or exams
